# Why am I unable to decrypt this AES encrypted string even though I have the key and IV?

Tags: encryption, aes

I am trying to figure out how a mobile app requests work so I can parse some data in my account.

It looks like they are encrypting their request payload and their response as well but they do send in the key and iv at every request.

I tried using an online decrypt tool like [this](https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator) by decoding the IV and key from base64, however it complains that the key is longer than 32 characters. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
{
    "RequestKey": "zDmNGDRrzNxWEeWX1NThsehsYW3MD/VA7DIcLQ61RuRe7K6sZFUyhaL8+trTzDYoTcTsRtFBbGUawizDJHnm7GfO086sfC/Y0JZ1iViduw1Clw24vAEwlOtRRph9/BF/zwhpHBk2bokKqNNc9K4G62Z5OrRLqyAxfMec7OWK5pOe9pc4ekj+noFBUfF34KsJ9TP/w3qvTlyemrE/qKPEecqttsGoFmFeh5eyPI9AK9sy7zqzd0TVWywwVu7i2niLoOQdb+2awIvFL9Suedep4mwnoUeboepLqnvxR8dyPEk+jT0JyQoma97Qz0+ZKGNaArL6LTOW0Y2A0lXAgWkBcw==",
    "RequestData": "G5/RGRc7XY1GSfU9FTBzgW0p5bVqzfshHZ5/UQQlea82iVRyWbsLPRgbs4zmfLZYbJn6TpmhSnYpw8EIjuVchv6VvmYwoDiZP9zK9Sqifv/TN/m8rQ4BLMQ4h2HvmFXxAolxHNLf2J4No2nZ/SWpYmoAaYOTaawe7nm/z5WVF9BGX1nNTzezeGCIf5RpmoH89dPkK1eBNbM4Ud582IWwggFCKtCEdJ4CJs2Qajt4x4D/o4j5lskAV/LGoStZ7PXpPTj2lX14fF1ADZ4fczAYAWPVQQQZl5A3pKI8s9iDJ9AZQgCz89zd8W1H0R0TVQt91Z5C7CDCJ1zd63/wAmGSG7Wlr43X0CnKH4UBytf/6jjoGUKxf+1VY1FVT7rmz/lT",
    "RequestIv": "Sml4MGc0MjZ2VkFlUDlHOA=="
}
```

And the response looks like this:

```
{ 
"ResponseData":     "....<truncated>...",
"ResponseIv": "2oeVI+asIWm6ECu4CfpU0A\u003d\u003d" 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to know the entire algorithm. Nothing here particularly suggests this is AES. The key is 2048 bits long, which could be RSA, but it could just as easily be a wrapped key (i.e. a key encrypted by another key). There wouldn't be much point in encrypting the data with a key they send over the same channel. Generally speaking, Stack Overflow is not a reverse engineering service. We answer concrete questions, but "how does this unnamed system with no description work" is not something we can really help with

Comment: The 2048 bit key has small factors when viewed as little-endian or big-endian, so it's likely not an rsa modulus. I'd guess it's a wrapped key, wrapped with RSA. But that's just a guess.